# PDE Book recommendations for Undergraduate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation, linear-pde

What is the best book of partial differential equation that contains homogeneous and inhomogeneous high order linear PDE such as undetermined coefficient methods to find particular solutions from PDE (analytic solution)?

I've been searching for that material and still haven't found it in books like Stanley, Strauss, Evan, or Michael Taylor. Their material is too advanced for beginners like me.

Comment: Maybe you can look for the following books:
Fourier Analysis and its applications - Folland ;
Fourier Analysis - Stein

Comment: Maybe [**A First Course in Partial Differential Equations**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/048668640X) by Hans F. Weinberger (1965; 1995 corrected reprint by Dover). This book is one of relatively few PDE books that is MORE advanced than the multitude of applied separation of variables books for engineers and physicists and LESS advanced than pure mathematical treatments that assume some Lebesgue integration. However, I don't know whether it fully satisfies your need for "high order linear PDE" material --- look at the table of contents at amazon and see what you think.